# UWP NavigationView Remove Transition Animation

Tags: xaml, user-interface, uwp, uwp-xaml

So I am using the fall creators update `NavigationView` UI Element.

When this element has `navView.DisplayMode = NavigationViewDisplayMode.Compact` there is a brief animation of the pane expanding/contracting when you press the hamburger button.

I want to disable this animation so the pane open/closes instantaneously.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I would assume you could overwrite this via the ```Template```.  I opened this in blend, tried to edit the template, and although it's a lot, I did not see any ```Storyboard``` portions.  This may be hard coded which would be wrong on the engineers side.  I'm looking deeper into the ```Template``` to see if I'm missing anything.

Comment: Well, it looks like you're going to have to write a custom control that works similar in order to remove the animation. I'm not 100% but I made a new custom control inherited from ```NavigationView``` with no luck and I've attempted to modify the ```Template``` and ```HeaderTemplate``` for it as well with no luck.  I don't see any top level control over that animation... It should be in the ```Template``` but it's not.  Anyway, good luck and post if you do find an answer.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII Yah that's the same conclusion I came to. Thanks for your effor though!

Comment: I tested the official app, and didn't see the animation effects. What's animation effect did you get on your side? For example, refresh , Drill or entry?

Answer (score 1):

NavigationView use SplitView, and animation is implemented by SplitView.
Copy `<Style TargetType="SplitView">` to your app.xaml or page, then replace all 
KeyTime="0:0:a.b" to KeyTime="0:0:0"

```
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition From="Closed" To="OpenOverlayLeft">

                                    <Storyboard>
                                       ...
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.35" KeySpline="0.1,0.9 0.2,1.0" Value="0" />
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Like KeyTime="0:0:0.35" above, change it to "0:0:0.00"

```
<SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.00" KeySpline="0.1,0.9 0.2,1.0" Value="0" />
```